# How to understand LibGDX crash logs on iOS device

Tags: ios, libgdx, robovm

My libgdx app crashes from time to time on an iOS device. I received the device log from xcode, but it does not highlight any exception cause. The log mentions the line where it crashes (object creation in box2d - `Body body = freeBodies.obtain();`), but it is not visible why. I followed this apple guide, but no listed cause matches my log: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/identifying-the-cause-of-common-crashes

How to find out what really happened?

Log:

```
follow instructions on
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/diagnosing-issues-using-crash-reports-and-device-logs


Incident Identifier: 8F1182F9-753C-483C-82AC-A4D52F252974
CrashReporter Key:   3fd2546244b1319333da0b865d96a392cee32986
Hardware Model:      iPhone11,8
Process:             IOSLauncher [19630]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/135D3CE3-489C-46E5-A0BD-206F6A884B63/IOSLauncher.app/IOSLauncher
Identifier:          com.myorg.myapp
Version:             1.0 (1)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      Exited process [19629]
Coalition:           com.myorg.myapp [816]

Date/Time:           2022-11-02 12:33:29.7557 +0000
Launch Time:         2022-11-02 12:30:55.8885 +0000
OS Version:          iPhone OS 15.6.1 (19G82)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    4.04.02
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000300000000
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000300000000
VM Region Info: 0x300000000 is not in any region.  Bytes after previous region: 1610612737  Bytes before following region: 54760833024
      REGION TYPE                 START - END      [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      MALLOC_NANO              280000000-2a0000000 [512.0M] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  
--->  GAP OF 0xd20000000 BYTES
      commpage (reserved)      fc0000000-1000000000 [  1.0G] ---/--- SM=NUL  ...(unallocated)
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 11 Segmentation fault: 11
Terminating Process: exc handler [19630]

Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:   Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   IOSLauncher                            0x104d4bb10 0x104b1c000 + 2292496
1   IOSLauncher                            0x104d5853c 0x104b1c000 + 2344252
2   IOSLauncher                            0x104d5853c 0x104b1c000 + 2344252
3   IOSLauncher                            0x104d5c120 0x104b1c000 + 2359584
4   IOSLauncher                            0x10503659c 0x104b1c000 + 5350812
5   IOSLauncher                            0x1050364d0 [J]com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World.createBody(Lcom/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/BodyDef;)Lcom/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/Body; + 5350608 (World.java:287)
6   IOSLauncher                            0x105171628 [J]com.myorg.myapp.utils.BodyBuilder.createBox(Lcom/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/World;FFFFZZFSSSF)Lcom/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/Body; + 6641192 (BodyBuilder.java:41)
7   IOSLauncher                            0x105171358 0x104b1c000 + 6640472
8   IOSLauncher                            0x10510fae8 [J]com.myorg.myapp.characters.model.Crab.createCrab(Lcom/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/World;)V + 6241000 (Crab.java:624)
9   IOSLauncher                            0x10510d4fc [J]com.myorg.myapp.characters.model.Crab.<init>(Lcom/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/TextureAtlas;Lcom/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/World;SSFZLcom/badlogic/gdx/math/Vector2;Lcom/myorg/myapp/gamelogic/BackgroundController;Lcom/myorg/myapp/characters/controllers/ExplosivesController;IILcom/myorg/myapp/characters/model/submodel/BalloonData;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;SLcom/myorg/myapp/characters/model/accessory/Accessory;Lcom/myorg/myapp/characters/model/accessory/Accessory;Lcom/myorg/myapp/characters/model/Crab$CRAB_CLASS;Z)V + 6231292 (Crab.java:224)
10  IOSLauncher                            0x1051248bc [J]com.myorg.myapp.characters.model.VillainCrab.<init>(Lcom/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/TextureAtlas;Lcom/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/World;Lcom/myorg/myapp/music/MusicController;SSFZLcom/myorg/myapp/characters/model/submodel/BalloonData;Lcom/badlogic/gdx/math/Vector2;Lcom/myorg/myapp/characters/controllers/FoxesController;Lcom/myorg/myapp/characters/controllers/DancersController;Lcom/myorg/myapp/gamelogic/BackgroundController;Lcom/myorg/myapp/characters/controllers/ExplosivesController;Lcom/myorg/myapp/gamelogic/WaveController;Lcom/myorg/myapp/characters/controllers/VillainCrabsController;Lcom/myorg/myapp/characters/controllers/TurretController;IIILcom/myorg/myapp/characters/model/accessory/Accessory;Lcom/myorg/myapp/characters/model/accessory/Accessory;IIFLcom/myorg/myapp/characters/model/Crab$CRAB_CLASS;Ljava/lang/Object;Z)V + 6326460 (VillainCrab.java:31)
11  IOSLauncher                            0x10510b874 [J]com.myorg.myapp.characters.controllers.VillainCrabsController.spawnCrab(Lcom/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/TextureAtlas;Lcom/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/World;Lcom/myorg/myapp/gamelogic/BackgroundController;Lcom/myorg/myapp/characters/controllers/ExplosivesController;Lcom/myorg/myapp/music/MusicController;Lcom/myorg/myapp/characters/controllers/FoxesController;Lcom/myorg/myapp/characters/controllers/TurretController;SSFZLcom/myorg/myapp/characters/controllers/DancersController;Lcom/myorg/myapp/gamelogic/WaveController;IIILcom/myorg/myapp/characters/model/accessory/Accessory;Lcom/myorg/myapp/characters/model/accessory/Accessory;IIFLcom/myorg/myapp/characters/model/submodel/BalloonData;Lcom/myorg/myapp/characters/model/Crab$CRAB_CLASS;Ljava/lang/Object;ZLcom/myorg/myapp/utils/Constants$SPAWN_SIDE;)V + 6223988 (VillainCrabsController.java:58)
12  IOSLauncher                            0x104dc0f2c 0x104b1c000 + 2772780
13  IOSLauncher                            0x1051331e0 [J]com.myorg.myapp.levels.LevelSpawner.spawn(Lcom/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/TextureAtlas;Lcom/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/World;F)V + 6386144 (LevelSpawner.java:46)
14  IOSLauncher                            0x10512b770 [J]com.myorg.myapp.gamelogic.WaveController.update(Lcom/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/TextureAtlas;FLcom/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/World;)V + 6354800 (WaveController.java:180)
15  IOSLauncher                            0x1051640c0 [J]com.myorg.myapp.states.PlayState.update(F)V + 6586560 (PlayState.java:391)
16  IOSLauncher                            0x10512a078 [J]com.myorg.myapp.gamelogic.GameStateController.update(F)V + 6348920 (GameStateController.java:39)
17  IOSLauncher                            0x1050f57ec [J]com.myorg.myapp.MyApp.render()V + 6133740 (MyApp.java:41)
18  IOSLauncher                            0x104f3c47c [J]com.badlogic.gdx.backends.iosrobovm.IOSGraphics.draw(Lorg/robovm/apple/glkit/GLKView;Lorg/robovm/apple/coregraphics/CGRect;)V + 4326524 (IOSGraphics.java:241)
19  IOSLauncher                            0x104f3d6d0 [J]com.badlogic.gdx.backends.iosrobovm.IOSGraphics$1.draw(Lorg/robovm/apple/coregraphics/CGRect;)V + 4331216 (IOSGraphics$1.java:131)
20  IOSLauncher                            0x104f3d7c8 0x104b1c000 + 4331464
21  IOSLauncher                            0x104f3d52c 0x104b1c000 + 4330796
22  IOSLauncher                            0x104f3d5a8 0x104b1c000 + 4330920
23  GLKit                                  0x1ff64c798 -[GLKView _display:] + 252
24  GLKit                                  0x1ff66b4a0 -[GLKViewController _updateAndDraw] + 480
25  QuartzCore                             0x1c618e840 CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 748
26  QuartzCore                             0x1c6195878 display_timer_callback(__CFMachPort*, void*, long, void*) + 372
27  CoreFoundation                         0x1c2446bf0 __CFMachPortPerform + 176
28  CoreFoundation                         0x1c248a258 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 60
29  CoreFoundation                         0x1c248da64 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 604
30  CoreFoundation                         0x1c2447664 __CFRunLoopRun + 2372
31  CoreFoundation                         0x1c245abc8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
32  GraphicsServices                       0x1de5c6374 GSEventRunModal + 164
33  UIKitCore                              0x1c4dceb58 -[UIApplication _run] + 1100
34  UIKitCore                              0x1c4b50090 UIApplicationMain + 364
35  IOSLauncher                            0x1055ee49c 0x104b1c000 + 11347100
36  IOSLauncher                            0x1055ed86c [J]org.robovm.apple.uikit.UIApplication.main([Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;)V + 11343980 (UIApplication.java:433)
37  IOSLauncher                            0x1055ec9e8 0x104b1c000 + 11340264
38  IOSLauncher                            0x1050f5bd8 [J]com.myorg.myapp.IOSLauncher.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V + 6134744 (IOSLauncher.java:19)
39  IOSLauncher                            0x1058fb7b8 catch_exception_raise + 95556
40  IOSLauncher                            0x1058f1918 catch_exception_raise + 54948
41  IOSLauncher                            0x1058f412c catch_exception_raise + 65208
42  IOSLauncher                            0x1058f41c0 catch_exception_raise + 65356
43  IOSLauncher                            0x1058ec2ec catch_exception_raise + 32888
44  IOSLauncher                            0x1058e1b1c 0x104b1c000 + 14441244
45  dyld                                   0x106b39da4 start + 520

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1f9f72f24 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x23369c298 _pthread_cond_wait + 1236
2   IOSLauncher                            0x1059152f4 catch_exception_raise + 200832
3   IOSLauncher                            0x10590d6e4 catch_exception_raise + 169072
4   IOSLauncher                            0x105913b38 catch_exception_raise + 194756
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x2336959ac _pthread_start + 148
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x233694e68 thread_start + 8

... truncated - similar output like in Thread 1 ...

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1f9f72f24 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x23369c298 _pthread_cond_wait + 1236
2   IOSLauncher                            0x1058f5e98 catch_exception_raise + 72740
3   IOSLauncher                            0x1051ca47c 0x104b1c000 + 7005308
4   IOSLauncher                            0x1051ca414 [J]java.lang.Object.wait()V + 7005204 (Object.java:365)
5   IOSLauncher                            0x1051bd168 [J]java.lang.Daemons$ReferenceQueueDaemon.run()V + 6951272 (Daemons$ReferenceQueueDaemon.java:129)
6   IOSLauncher                            0x1051e551c [J]java.lang.Thread.run()V + 7116060 (Thread.java:839)
7   IOSLauncher                            0x1058fb7b8 catch_exception_raise + 95556
8   IOSLauncher                            0x1058f1918 catch_exception_raise + 54948
9   IOSLauncher                            0x1058f153c catch_exception_raise + 53960
10  IOSLauncher                            0x1058facc4 catch_exception_raise + 92752
11  IOSLauncher                            0x1059138f8 catch_exception_raise + 194180
12  IOSLauncher                            0x105910aa4 catch_exception_raise + 182320
13  IOSLauncher                            0x105914d68 catch_exception_raise + 199412
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x2336959ac _pthread_start + 148
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x233694e68 thread_start + 8

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1f9f72f24 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x23369c298 _pthread_cond_wait + 1236
2   IOSLauncher                            0x1058f5e98 catch_exception_raise + 72740
3   IOSLauncher                            0x1051ca47c 0x104b1c000 + 7005308
4   IOSLauncher                            0x1051ca434 [J]java.lang.Object.wait(J)V + 7005236 (Object.java:402)
5   IOSLauncher                            0x1051f0d60 [J]java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(J)Ljava/lang/ref/Reference; + 7163232 (ReferenceQueue.java:103)
6   IOSLauncher                            0x1051f09e0 0x104b1c000 + 7162336
7   IOSLauncher                            0x1051f0cac [J]java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove()Ljava/lang/ref/Reference; + 7163052 (ReferenceQueue.java:73)
8   IOSLauncher                            0x1051bc4bc [J]java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run()V + 6948028 (Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.java:170)
9   IOSLauncher                            0x1051e551c [J]java.lang.Thread.run()V + 7116060 (Thread.java:839)
10  IOSLauncher                            0x1058fb7b8 catch_exception_raise + 95556
11  IOSLauncher                            0x1058f1918 catch_exception_raise + 54948
12  IOSLauncher                            0x1058f153c catch_exception_raise + 53960
13  IOSLauncher                            0x1058facc4 catch_exception_raise + 92752
14  IOSLauncher                            0x1059138f8 catch_exception_raise + 194180
15  IOSLauncher                            0x105910aa4 catch_exception_raise + 182320
16  IOSLauncher                            0x105914d68 catch_exception_raise + 199412
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x2336959ac _pthread_start + 148
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x233694e68 thread_start + 8

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1f9f72f24 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x23369c298 _pthread_cond_wait + 1236
2   IOSLauncher                            0x1058f5e5c catch_exception_raise + 72680
3   IOSLauncher                            0x1058f61a0 catch_exception_raise + 73516
4   IOSLauncher                            0x1051e5ef4 0x104b1c000 + 7118580
5   IOSLauncher                            0x1051e5e84 [J]java.lang.Thread.sleep(JI)V + 7118468 (Thread.java:1010)
6   IOSLauncher                            0x1051e5e68 [J]java.lang.Thread.sleep(J)V + 7118440 (Thread.java:992)
7   IOSLauncher                            0x1051e2d58 0x104b1c000 + 7105880
8   IOSLauncher                            0x1051bccb0 [J]java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.sleepFor(JJ)V + 6950064 (Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.java:253)
9   IOSLauncher                            0x1051bcd98 [J]java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.waitForFinalization(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z + 6950296 (Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.java:259)
10  IOSLauncher                            0x1051bc958 [J]java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.run()V + 6949208 (Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.java:212)
11  IOSLauncher                            0x1051e551c [J]java.lang.Thread.run()V + 7116060 (Thread.java:839)
12  IOSLauncher                            0x1058fb7b8 catch_exception_raise + 95556
13  IOSLauncher                            0x1058f1918 catch_exception_raise + 54948
14  IOSLauncher                            0x1058f153c catch_exception_raise + 53960
15  IOSLauncher                            0x1058facc4 catch_exception_raise + 92752
16  IOSLauncher                            0x1059138f8 catch_exception_raise + 194180
17  IOSLauncher                            0x105910aa4 catch_exception_raise + 182320
18  IOSLauncher                            0x105914d68 catch_exception_raise + 199412
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x2336959ac _pthread_start + 148
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x233694e68 thread_start + 8

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x233694e54 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 11 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1f9f724a0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1f9f72ae4 mach_msg + 76
2   CoreFoundation                         0x1c2442d30 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372
3   CoreFoundation                         0x1c24471bc __CFRunLoopRun + 1180
4   CoreFoundation                         0x1c245abc8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
5   Foundation                             0x1c3c4d444 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 236
6   Foundation                             0x1c3c8ee0c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 92
7   UIKitCore                              0x1c4d48cc4 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 524
8   Foundation                             0x1c3c9d41c __NSThread__start__ + 808
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x2336959ac _pthread_start + 148
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x233694e68 thread_start + 8

Thread 12 name:  AVAudioSession Notify Thread
Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1f9f724a0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1f9f72ae4 mach_msg + 76
2   CoreFoundation                         0x1c2442d30 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372
3   CoreFoundation                         0x1c24471bc __CFRunLoopRun + 1180
4   CoreFoundation                         0x1c245abc8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
5   AudioSession                           0x1cba6ff04 CADeprecated::GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 164
6   AudioSession                           0x1cba798f0 CADeprecated::CAPThread::Entry(CADeprecated::CAPThread*) + 92
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x2336959ac _pthread_start + 148
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x233694e68 thread_start + 8

Thread 13 name:  com.apple.CoreMotion.MotionThread
Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1f9f724a0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1f9f72ae4 mach_msg + 76
2   CoreFoundation                         0x1c2442d30 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372
3   CoreFoundation                         0x1c24471bc __CFRunLoopRun + 1180
4   CoreFoundation                         0x1c245abc8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
5   CoreFoundation                         0x1c24dbda8 CFRunLoopRun + 64
6   CoreMotion                             0x1cf8f9a9c 0x1cf8e7000 + 76444
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x2336959ac _pthread_start + 148
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x233694e68 thread_start + 8

Thread 14 name:  AURemoteIO::IOThread
Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1f9f724a0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1f9f72ae4 mach_msg + 76
2   libEmbeddedSystemAUs.dylib             0x1fedb9f38 void* caulk::thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<caulk::thread::attributes, AURemoteIO::IOThread::IOThread(AURemoteIO&, caulk::thread::attributes const&, caulk::mach::os_workgroup const&)::'lambda'(), std::__1::tuple<> > >(void*) + 548
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x2336959ac _pthread_start + 148
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x233694e68 thread_start + 8

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1f9f72f24 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x23369c298 _pthread_cond_wait + 1236
2   IOSLauncher                            0x1058f5e5c catch_exception_raise + 72680
3   IOSLauncher                            0x1051ca47c 0x104b1c000 + 7005308
4   IOSLauncher                            0x1051ca434 [J]java.lang.Object.wait(J)V + 7005236 (Object.java:402)
5   IOSLauncher                            0x1050ee410 [J]com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Timer$TimerThread.run()V + 6104080 (Timer$TimerThread.java:287)
6   IOSLauncher                            0x1051e551c [J]java.lang.Thread.run()V + 7116060 (Thread.java:839)
7   IOSLauncher                            0x1058fb7b8 catch_exception_raise + 95556
8   IOSLauncher                            0x1058f1918 catch_exception_raise + 54948
9   IOSLauncher                            0x1058f153c catch_exception_raise + 53960
10  IOSLauncher                            0x1058facc4 catch_exception_raise + 92752
11  IOSLauncher                            0x1059138f8 catch_exception_raise + 194180
12  IOSLauncher                            0x105910aa4 catch_exception_raise + 182320
13  IOSLauncher                            0x105914d68 catch_exception_raise + 199412
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x2336959ac _pthread_start + 148
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x233694e68 thread_start + 8

Thread 16:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1f9f72f24 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x23369c298 _pthread_cond_wait + 1236
2   IOSLauncher                            0x1058f5e98 catch_exception_raise + 72740
3   IOSLauncher                            0x1051ca47c 0x104b1c000 + 7005308
4   IOSLauncher                            0x1051e6834 [J]java.lang.Thread.parkFor(J)V + 7120948 (Thread.java:1210)
5   IOSLauncher                            0x1058e188c [J]sun.misc.Unsafe.park(ZJ)V + 14440588 (Unsafe.java:381)
6   IOSLauncher                            0x105339874 [J]java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Ljava/lang/Object;)V + 8509556 (LockSupport.java:158)
7   IOSLauncher                            0x1053396b8 0x104b1c000 + 8509112
8   IOSLauncher                            0x105338948 [J]java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await()V + 8505672 (AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.java:2018)
9   IOSLauncher                            0x1053262cc [J]java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take()Ljava/lang/Object; + 8430284 (LinkedBlockingQueue.java:409)
10  IOSLauncher                            0x1053300e8 [J]java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask()Ljava/lang/Runnable; + 8470760 (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1037)
11  IOSLauncher                            0x10533029c [J]java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Ljava/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker;)V + 8471196 (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1097)
12  IOSLauncher                            0x1053329f4 [J]java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run()V + 8481268 (ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.java:588)
13  IOSLauncher                            0x1051e551c [J]java.lang.Thread.run()V + 7116060 (Thread.java:839)
14  IOSLauncher                            0x1058fb7b8 catch_exception_raise + 95556
15  IOSLauncher                            0x1058f1918 catch_exception_raise + 54948
16  IOSLauncher                            0x1058f153c catch_exception_raise + 53960
17  IOSLauncher                            0x1058facc4 catch_exception_raise + 92752
18  IOSLauncher                            0x1059138f8 catch_exception_raise + 194180
19  IOSLauncher                            0x105910aa4 catch_exception_raise + 182320
20  IOSLauncher                            0x105914d68 catch_exception_raise + 199412
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x2336959ac _pthread_start + 148
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x233694e68 thread_start + 8

Thread 17:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1f9f72f24 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x23369c298 _pthread_cond_wait + 1236
2   IOSLauncher                            0x1058f5e98 catch_exception_raise + 72740
3   IOSLauncher                            0x1051ca47c 0x104b1c000 + 7005308
4   IOSLauncher                            0x1051e6834 [J]java.lang.Thread.parkFor(J)V + 7120948 (Thread.java:1210)
5   IOSLauncher                            0x1058e188c [J]sun.misc.Unsafe.park(ZJ)V + 14440588 (Unsafe.java:381)
6   IOSLauncher                            0x105339874 [J]java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Ljava/lang/Object;)V + 8509556 (LockSupport.java:158)
7   IOSLauncher                            0x1053396b8 0x104b1c000 + 8509112
8   IOSLauncher                            0x105338948 [J]java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await()V + 8505672 (AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.java:2018)
9   IOSLauncher                            0x1053262cc [J]java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take()Ljava/lang/Object; + 8430284 (LinkedBlockingQueue.java:409)
10  IOSLauncher                            0x1053300e8 [J]java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask()Ljava/lang/Runnable; + 8470760 (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1037)
11  IOSLauncher                            0x10533029c [J]java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Ljava/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker;)V + 8471196 (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1097)
12  IOSLauncher                            0x1053329f4 [J]java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run()V + 8481268 (ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.java:588)
13  IOSLauncher                            0x1051e551c [J]java.lang.Thread.run()V + 7116060 (Thread.java:839)
14  IOSLauncher                            0x1058fb7b8 catch_exception_raise + 95556
15  IOSLauncher                            0x1058f1918 catch_exception_raise + 54948
16  IOSLauncher                            0x1058f153c catch_exception_raise + 53960
17  IOSLauncher                            0x1058facc4 catch_exception_raise + 92752
18  IOSLauncher                            0x1059138f8 catch_exception_raise + 194180
19  IOSLauncher                            0x105910aa4 catch_exception_raise + 182320
20  IOSLauncher                            0x105914d68 catch_exception_raise + 199412
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x2336959ac _pthread_start + 148
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x233694e68 thread_start + 8

... truncated - similar output like in Thread 1 ...

Thread 19:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x233694e54 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 20:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x233694e54 start_wqthread + 0


Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000300000000   x1: 0x00000000000000b8   x2: 0x00000001583b8000   x3: 0x0000000000000002
    x4: 0x0000000000000001   x5: 0x0000000000000001   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x0000000106613998   x9: 0x0000000000000000  x10: 0x000000010dd66780  x11: 0x000000000000010d
   x12: 0x00001f0000001f02  x13: 0x00001f0000001f00  x14: 0x0000020000000000  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0x0000000233695154  x17: 0x0000020000000202  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x00000001583b8000
   x20: 0x000000016b2e0330  x21: 0x00000001583b8040  x22: 0x0000000000000006  x23: 0x0000000000000000
   x24: 0x0000000107466000  x25: 0x000000010692ffa0  x26: 0x0000000107a03390  x27: 0x0000000107a03420
   x28: 0x0000000107a74b90   fp: 0x000000016b2e02f0   lr: 0x0000000104d5853c
    sp: 0x000000016b2e02c0   pc: 0x0000000104d4bb10 cpsr: 0x80000000
   far: 0x00000002190f8998  esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault

Binary Images:
       0x104b1c000 -        0x105e8bfff IOSLauncher arm64  <6065b839b23530c790255cfffc7f0e85> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/135D3CE3-489C-46E5-A0BD-206F6A884B63/IOSLauncher.app/IOSLauncher
       0x1ff64b000 -        0x1ff679fff GLKit arm64e  <36159248a30e366b8ee84275736a7f1d> /System/Library/Frameworks/GLKit.framework/GLKit
       0x1c617e000 -        0x1c648ffff QuartzCore arm64e  <df21293e9dbf37a58506d0c7f3d8646c> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
       0x1c243c000 -        0x1c2891fff CoreFoundation arm64e  <6b22dd8135853be6bc77ba19810ec0f2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
       0x1de5c5000 -        0x1de5cdfff GraphicsServices arm64e  <a094e7b51d4037c5902756d86988ec4b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
       0x1c48ba000 -        0x1c6157fff UIKitCore arm64e  <137a95aada6d332cbc01e13bb9b6e317> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore
       0x106b20000 -        0x106b77fff dyld arm64e  <66e1fb2668f8379ba052eb8b8291b5e1> /usr/lib/dyld
       0x1f9f71000 -        0x1f9fa6fff libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64e  <1fb39303587b320eaeb8e51a54c8a4a9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
       0x233694000 -        0x23369ffff libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64e  <adc41700002e3a2bb4a1eb5fbf575770> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
       0x1c3c34000 -        0x1c3f3efff Foundation arm64e  <ee1abaf23d7137fb906715aa79528619> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
       0x1cba69000 -        0x1cba93fff AudioSession arm64e  <98e4676874ff374c9b70303bffce2d33> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AudioSession.framework/AudioSession
       0x1cf8e7000 -        0x1cfc00fff CoreMotion arm64e  <9f45d028cdd833daab156f34eae67b38> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
       0x1fedb7000 -        0x1feec2fff libEmbeddedSystemAUs.dylib arm64e  <b096af4e229236c8876e6873a43112fd> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/libEmbeddedSystemAUs.dylib
       0x1cd11e000 -        0x1cd3aefff AudioToolbox arm64e  <eeda441c4ed331be9ca5782c3d14a76e> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
       0x1dbbb1000 -        0x1dbbe4fff libAudioToolboxUtility.dylib arm64e  <fb92b354a610382ca3245fd9b6277d0d> /usr/lib/libAudioToolboxUtility.dylib
               0x0 - 0xffffffffffffffff ??? unknown-arch  <00000000000000000000000000000000> ???

EOF
```

Code:

```
    /** Create a rigid body given a definition. No reference to the definition is retained.
     * Bodies created by this method are pooled internally by the World object.
     * They will be freed upon calling {@link World#destroyBody(Body)}
     * @see Pool
     * @warning This function is locked during callbacks. */
    public Body createBody (BodyDef def) {
        long bodyAddr = jniCreateBody(addr, def.type.getValue(), def.position.x, def.position.y, def.angle, def.linearVelocity.x,
            def.linearVelocity.y, def.angularVelocity, def.linearDamping, def.angularDamping, def.allowSleep, def.awake,
            def.fixedRotation, def.bullet, def.active, def.gravityScale);
        Body body = freeBodies.obtain();
        body.reset(bodyAddr);
        this.bodies.put(body.addr, body);
        return body;
    }
```

Comment: If you are sure the `Body body = freeBodies.obtain();` is line 287 in World.java, please tell us more about the 'freeBodies' object. Also, SIGSEGV exception means your app is accessing incorrect memory address, so maybe if `freeBodies.obtain()` is some kind of pool and does something with cached addresses, chances are, those addresses may no longer be valid.

Comment: freebodies.obtain(); is actually a code line of the library which i use (box2d). its called when i create new objects. I got some more insight and I think its related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22934386/libgdx-destroying-a-body However, I do get the error only when creating objects (destroying objects as mentioned in above link works for me since I follow the suggested answers already).